# A JSP page creates a JSESSIONID cookie where not appropriate

Tags: java, jsp, session

When I visit my page `.../index.jsp` while having no `HttpSession`s, `index.jsp` still creates the `JSESSIONID`-cookie. Even worse, in the servlet responsible for logging people out, `session.invalidate()` does not seem to fix the issue.

`index.jsp` looks like this:

```
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.Cookie"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@page session="true"%>

<%!
    void removeJSessionIdCookie(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JESSIONID", "");
        cookie.setValue(null);
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
%>


<%
    if (session != null) {
        out.print("Session not null.");
        if (session.getAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_ATTRIBUTE) != null) {
            out.print("have user"); 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("app.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        } else {
            out.println("no user here");
            session.invalidate();
            removeJSessionIdCookie(response);
        }
    }
%>
<html>...</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `session="true"` in your `<%@page%>` directive, then the JSP framework code always creates a new session if the calling client does not bring a session cookie, i.e. has no session yet.

You need to put `session="false"` in to the page directive; this makes the Framework stop creating sessions for you.